# Gateway m-1625 laptop keeps shutting down

Tags: shutdown

I have a gateway m-1625 laptop. The specs are: 3gig DDR2 ram, amd turino*2 processor 2Ghz, 250gig HD, windows 7 ultimate.

After installing Ubuntu 11.10 and using it for about an hour my laptop starts shutting down most times before even reaching the log on screen. I have re installed it twice but the problem still persist. I had this same problem with ubuntu 11.04. I have been using ubuntu for the last 5 years and never had this problem before. Windows 7, vista and fedora runs fine, it just ubuntu that gives any sort of issue. What could be causing this problem? has something critical been changed since the 10.10 version? I really love ubuntu and i want to be able to run it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there have been rather extreme changes since 10.10 -- by far the larges changes in the history of Ubuntu. It has been necessary to replace key platform software and vital to do so quickly since the next version of Ubuntu in April will be supported for five years and everything needs to be in place by then. It would've been better if Gnome 3 and other key technologies, had been ready in March 2010 so Ubuntu would have the full two years to make the transition. Alas, that's not how the world works, so we better make the best of it. Because of these large changes in such a short timespan, Ubuntu is temporarily not as rock solid as it usually is. Luckily, though, 10.04 will be supported for a couple of years more, and even 10.10 will be supported until 12.04 is released, by which time most of the issues should be resolved. In other words, if 10.10 works and 11.04 doesn't, then you have the option of postponing the upgrade.

It is useful to know that things work in Windows, but it would be more useful to know what version of Fedora you're comparing with. That way, we can compare versions of software like the kernel. If you have upgraded from an earlier version of Ubuntu, you can try to boot an older kernel while booting, by holding shift to show the grub menu. You can of course install older kernels anyway. If you need help with that, search for a question about it, or open a new one to handle that topic separately. These types of issues might be difficult to track down on a site like this, though.

My reusable recommendation is:

1. Stick to what works.
2. Don't fix it if it ain't broken
3. When in doubt, don't.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. its fedora 16 and i did a clean install for ubuntu 11.10, so booting on the older 10.10 kernel is out. think i will just go back to ubuntu 10.04LTS for the time being. benn trying to substitute with feodra 16 but its not growing on me.